# Passing values being components which use Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to pass functions down through components, and how do I the callback?

This is `ListContainer.jsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Internal
import Results from '../Results';
import List from '../List';


const ListContainer = () => {

  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = (countryISO3) => {
    // fetch data and store in countries
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Results />
      {results && (
        <>
          <List items={results} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default ListContainer;
```

This is the `Results.jsx` component.

```
const Results = (props) => {

  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // useCallback(event.target.value) ?
  };

  const loadResults = () => {
    // fetch results;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadResults();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {results.map(result => (
        {result.name}
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

Comment: do you have redux setup? because it would make such parameter passing quite easy.

Comment: Or you could use React context too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need to pass the fetch function down from the `ListContainer` to the `Results` component so that it can be called in the `onSelect` event.

Change `<Results />` to `<Results fetch={fetchData} />`

Then in your `Results` component, `handleChange` should look like this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setOrigin(event.target.value)
  if (event.length.value.length > 0) props.fetch(event.target.value)
};
```

This should solve your problem.

You could further improve this implementation by debouncing your `fetch` function, but that is out of this question scope.